# Seaside: URL to image on server

Tags: image, file-upload, seaside

I created an upload form for images, which works properly and saves files in Contents/Resources/uploads.

I now want to display those images in my web app: how do I retrieve the URL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To display a Seaside image, you'd use...

```
html url: <some image resource>
```

...if that image is in your Seaside image, the image resource can be coded as...

```
html url: WAFileLibrary / #myNewImagePng
```

...which translates as...

```
html url: '/files/WAFileLibrary/myNewImage.png'
```

Normally a subclass of WAFileLibrary would be used for your application.

Comment: Ok, I found something like `addAllFilesIn` in the Seaside config. But how do I tell the system to always make all files in one directory available? Or do I have to call this function every time I upload a picture?

Comment: We wrote a custom library that caches some images and reads the rest from file.

Answer (score 1):

It is not a question of Seaside but of the Webserver you use.

If you use Apache to serve the static files, you find the mechanism described here:
[Mapping URLs to Filesystem Locations](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/urlmapping.html)

If you work on Pharo, during development you could use Zinc webserver to serve static files:

```
ZnZincStaticServerAdaptor startOn: 8080 andServeFilesFrom: '/Path/to/the/images'
```

In this case the URL to upload.jpg in '/Path/to/the/images' would be for example `http://localhost:8080/upload.jpg`

Answer (score 0):

You need to configure your server to serve the files from your upload directory. Either Apache or your Smalltalk web server. Then you'll probably want to use `#resourceUrl:`

Check out the following chapters in the Seaside book

- [Serving Files > Images](http://book.seaside.st/book/in-action/serving-files/images)
- [Serving files with Apache](http://book.seaside.st/book/advanced/deployment/deployment-apache/serving-files)

Comment: The first link doesn't really say anything about resources in the `Content/Resources` directory.

Comment: Well yeah, that's just the directory in which you chose to upload it. You could as well have chosen any other directory.

Comment: Yes, but the documentation doesn't show me how to access any repository.

Comment: Yes it does, see the second link.

Comment: But I don't use Apache - guess I should have said that ;)